# Maven Version Tag

Tags: maven, tags, version, pom.xml, dependency-management

I am wondering what does this mean:

```
<version>${artifactId.version}</version>
```

Does this mean that version is always the current one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the version is defined by *`<artifactId.version>`* property:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <artifactId.version>3.0.0.1</artifactId.version>
</properties>
```

In this example, the version would be `3.0.0.1`.

Pay attention, also, to use the *`<project.build.sourceEncoding>`* and set the versions accordingly to your project needs.

Comment: So this, then basically means that we would always have a current version if we put ${artifactId.version} in our dependency version? And we also have to know whether such property exist in the dependency?!

Comment: @ilija: No, you still have to modify the property. The property should be in the POM which declares the dependency and not the dependency itself.

Comment: @ilija BTW: if you want to specify artifact versions in your parent POM, you can also use the `<dependencyManagement>` tag. See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management for more info.

Comment: This version tag is inside the project dependencies, right?  It means that the dependency declaration doesn't say which version of some other project Maven should pull in when building.  Instead it dereferences a project property.  If you want to build, you need to define the property `artifactId.version`, either as described above or via the command line, and its value needs to be an existing version number of the project you're depending on.

Comment: @ilija Everytime the current latest version changes, you will need to update its property in your pom.xml. So, if you put ${artifactId.version} in the artifact version and in the dependencies versions, then both will use the same version. All you need to do is update the property.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing a `$` sign before `{artifactId.version}`.

And it would mean that you're using this `artifactId.version` variable to determine the version of your artifact.

Comment: So if I have dependency and I want to get its version where in the version tag is: ${artifactId.version}. How I'm supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you can specify version outside maven, which is a common case.

Example:

```
mvn <operation> [params...] -DartifactId.version=1.2.3
```